# Accurate button placement and multiple screens. Android app development

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, button

I am currently developing an Android app using Eclipse and the Android SDK and I have an issue I can't seem to solve. That is to very accurately place buttons, textviews etc. on a layout.

Practically, i would like to be able to set an image background on a layout, place buttons on top of it in a very accurate way so that it would look the same on multiple screens. For example, if i were to set a white background image with crosses i drew randomly by hand, i would like the buttons to be placed on each cross and this accurately on multiple screen sizes. 
I know Android wants you to use dp units by default but the scaling makes it inaccurate in the end. Moreover, the background image stretching makes it worse.

The only possibility i have in mind is using pt units (72pt = inch) which is independent to scaling, get the screen size in pt and through weird and complex calculations place the buttons accurately but that seems a bit too complicated for a seemingly simple problem like this one.

Does anyone have any idea how i could accurately position many buttons (about 20) on a layout.xml so that it would look the same on different screens?

Thanks for your help.

Thomas

Comment: You'd be better off using a list view instead of a table layout - on a side note! Android provides means to acheive what you want without banging your head against the wall.

Comment: look into using weights with linear layouts. This will make sure all the button are in the same position ratio on every device. you have to remember that all devices have different aspect ratios so there is no way to make it look the exact same.

Comment: also, dont use a background image as layout element... Different phones will have different aspect ratios, resolutions and sizes, resulting the image to either be stretched or cropped (or both).